# "An error occurred while handling another error: yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException"

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to submit a comment on a guestbook application based on the Yii 2 Framework. On localhost on my PC works everything fine, but on the shared hosting when I want to submit a comment in View, I get this error.

Here is the error:

```
An error occurred while handling another error:
    exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/controllers/PostController.php on line 117.' in /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
    #1 /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()
    #2 /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
    #3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
    #4 {main}
    Previous exception:
    exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/controllers/PostController.php on line 117.' in /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
    #1 /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->send()
    #2 /home/mahdikas/public_html/guestbook/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
    #3 {main}
```

In the postController I have this code:

```
public function actionAdd_comment()
{
  //print_r($_POST);
  $model = new \app\models\Comments;
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    $model->comment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if ($model->save()) {
      echo 'Thanks for your comment.';
    } else {
      echo 'Failed!';
    }
  }
}
```

which line 117 in the error is:

```
echo 'Thanks for your comment.';
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are getting "Headers already sent" means you have white space before you redirecting to some other page

Comment: I've checked the codes but there was no white space. It's noticeable that although I get this error message, but the comment submitted successfully and it is saved in db.

Comment: add the code that is raising this exception

Comment: It's done. a part of PostController.php code has been added.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since Yii 2.0.14 you cannot echo in a controller. A response must be returned:

```
public function actionAdd_comment() {
    $model = new \app\models\Comments();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->comment_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if ($model->save()) {
            return 'Thanks for your comment.';
        } else {
            return 'Failed!';
        }
    }
}
```

---

You may also call `exit` at the end of your method to prevent further processing or wrap your code with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`, if you're not able to avoid echo.

```
public function actionAdd_comment() {
    $model = new \app\models\Comments();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $this->someMagicWithEcho();
        exit;
    }
}
```

or

```
public function actionAdd_comment() {
    $model = new \app\models\Comments();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        ob_start();
        $this->someMagicWithEcho();
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that you have to include exit in all functions?

Comment: It means that you should return response instead of echoing it. `exit` is only a solution when you're not able to avoid echo - it should be pretty rare situation.

Comment: I don't have an echo on any of my controllers, but I have also just encountered the error.

Comment: You definitely have have some output somewhere - it is either `echo` or some space before/after opening/closing PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you!! For some odd reason i had 3 conditions with an echo json at the end, and had no issues, then added a fourth and ran into this.. i added ``exit;`` at the end of each condition, and it was all good

Answer (score 2):

Although I accept [rob006's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689315/an-error-occurred-while-handling-another-error-yii-web-headersalreadysentexcept/49705418#49705418) as correct, I have encountered a situation where there was no echo in the controller, but I also got the error. After going through several sites looking for a solution, I discovered an alternative.

You can check the *php.ini* file and ensure the *output buffer* is enabled. If not, you can enable it by adding this line in *php.ini* if it does not exist:

```
output_buffering = on
```

And turn it off for just the script - the script where it is not required by either...

1. calling `ob_end_flush()`, or
2. calling `ob_end_clean()`